# Undefinided control sequense in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

**Hi such, I have a problem with the following code, specifically when I insert a resistor or an inductor, do not understand why it should be fail, agradeceria who could help me. regards**

```
     \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
     \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
     \usepackage{amsmath}
     \usepackage{amsfonts}
     \usepackage{amssymb}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{tikz}
     \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.45]
        \draw
        (0,0)     --                                (0,1.25)
        (0,1.25)     to[vsourcesin]                 (0,3)
        (0,2.5)   node[right]{$V_{an}(t)$}
        (0,3)     --                                (3,3)

        (1,0)      --                               (1,0.75)
        (1,0.75)     to[vsourcesin]                 (1,2.5)
        (1,2)   node[right]{$V_{bn}(t)$}
        (1,2.5)    --                               (4,2.5)

        (2,0)      --                               (2,0.25)
        (2,0.25)     to[vsourcesin]                 (2,2)
        (2,1.6)   node[right]{$V_{cn}(t)$}
        (2,2)      --                               (5,2)

        (0,0)       --                              (2,0)

        (2,0)      --                               (3,0)
        (3,0)       to[D*]                          (3,2.5)
        (3.2,1)   node[right]{$D_{1}$}
        (3,2.5)     to[Ty*]                         (3,5)
        (3.2,3.5) node[right]{$T_{1}$}

        (3,5)       --                              (4,5)
        (3,0)       --                              (4,0)
        (4,0)       to[D*]                          (4,2.5)
        (4.2,1)   node[right]{$D_{2}$}
        (4,2.5)     to[Ty*]                         (4,5)
        (4.2,3.5) node[right]{$T_{2}$}

        (4,5)       --                              (5,5)
        (4,0)       --                              (5,0)
        (5,0)       to[D*]                          (5,2.5)
        (5.2,1)   node[right]{$D_{3}$}
        (5,2.5)     to[Ty*]                         (5,5)
        (5.2,3.5) node[right]{$T_{3}$}

        (5,5)       --                              (6,5)
        (5,0)       --                              (6,0)

        (6,0)       to[R,l=$R_1$,mirror]            (6,3)
        (6,3)    to[L,l=$L_1$,mirror]               (6,5)       
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}    
    \end{document}
```

**The end result is this**

[image]

**
However when viewed the following is obtained**

[image]

*please help*

Comment: Do you want everybody to figure out what the error is or will you provide a minimum working example, so people can just compile your code and see the error. Of course, it would help if you could state the problem as well.

Comment: latex know but I'm new using circuitikz. the code works well according to documentation. The problem is that in trying to insert a resistor or a simple inductor throws me sequense undefined error control.. ej.- to [R,L=$R$];

Comment: There can be several possible reasons for the error. Your code doesn't show the main document class and it doesn't show the packages you include. Your code should include the document class and package inclusion command. Without that, you may find that nobody will even try seeing if they can help you.

Comment: I test your MWE (which should show your problem) and it works fine. Where you like to add a resistor or inductance? Do you have a special reason that you not used elements labels as defined in `circuitikz`?

Comment: thank your friends for help. the problem is the package circuitikz as only does not work for inductors and resistors, I still do not solve but it is a breakthrough ha ha ha. regards ....I found this and I'm trying to hit the nail    **  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316403/schematic-drawing-works-for-capacitors-but-not-for-the-inductors-and-resistors**

Comment: Any updates here?